# Message length restriction in RSA

Tags: ssl, rsa

In RSA the message length should not exceed the (keysize/8) bytes. Why is there such a restriction? What is the input(say "abcde") converted into before feeding it into the RSA algorithm and where doest it take into account the size of the the input string "abcde"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RSA algorithm is essentially:

```
Ciphertext = (Plaintext e) mod n
```

and to decrypt:

```
Plaintext = (Ciphertext d) mod n
```

`e` and `n` together make up your public key, and `d` and `n` make up your private key. `e` is usually one of a few common values, e.g. 65537, `n` is the product of two large prime numbers `p` and `q` which should be unique to you, and defines the key length (e.g. 1024 bits). The value of `d` used to decrypt the ciphertext is calculated using `e`, `p` and `q`. Wikipedia has more detail if you're interested: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(algorithm)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29). Your plaintext is basically treated as a large integer when used in the RSA algorithm.

In case you're not familiar with the modulo operator, it is basically the remainder when the left side is divided by the right side. E.g. `17 mod 5 = 2` as 5 exactly divides 17 three times (`3 * 5 = 15`), leaving a remainder of: `17 - 15 = 2`).

As a result of the definition of the modulo operator, the result of `a mod b` is always less than `b`. Given this, and the fact that the decrypted value is the result of performing a `mod n` operation means that when decrypted, the resulting plaintext value will always be less than n. Hence, for this to be the actual plaintext you originally encrypted, the input must be less than `n`.

To guarantee this, the message is restricted to having fewer bits ("digits") than `n`. Since the number of bits in `n` is the key size, it must must have fewer than `keysize bits`, or `keysize / 8 bytes` (since there are 8 bits in a byte).

Comment: I think you did not get my question. My question is that if there is an input string "abcde" that I want to encrypt with public key, how will hat be done. What will the "ancde" be converted to ?

Comment: It will be converted into a number. How you do that depends on what "ancde" represents. (For example, are upper-case letters legal? Are digits? Are punctuation marks?) How the input string is converted into a number (or that the input is a string) is not part of the RSA algorithm and is part of how it is specifically implemented. If you wanted to, you could, for example, represent 'a' by "01", 'b' by "02" and so on and do it in decimal. You could use 8-bit ASCII in binary.

Comment: @David Schwartz : So what you are saying is that "abcde" could be converted to something like this : "0102030405" and this to the power the public key will be the ciphertext?

Comment: Sure, if that's how you want to do it, you can do it that way. If you want to do it some other way, you can do it some other way. So long as both ends agree, RSA doesn't care. It works the same. (Understand, however, that not all methods will result in a *secure* cryptosystem. In fact, [most won't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Attacks_against_plain_RSA)!)

Comment: @David Schwartz : Then why is there not restriction on some algorithms that use a single secret key like the des?

Comment: There are. DES, for example, [encrypts 64-bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher#Lucifer_.2F_DES). You have to build it into a cryptosystem to encrypt larger chunks of data or streams of data. Typically, AES is used with padding to encrypt a key for a symmetric cipher used in such a way that it can encrypt arbitrary-sized chunks. (Such as a stream cipher or with a chaining mode and more padding.) You have to remember that things like RSA and DES are not cryptosystems. They're algorithms, primitives. They're the small parts we build complete systems out of.

Comment: @David Schwartz : okay .. thank you. If you please answer in the answer section, I will acccept it.